# Cocoapods ReactiveKit swift compiler error

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am trying to add ReactiveKit To my Xcode project with CocoaPods.

That is my pods file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target '<my-proj-name-here>' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SideMenu'
    pod 'ReactiveKit'
    pod 'Bond'
end
```

I ran the following lines from command line:

```
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Tons of errors are shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't enough familiar with cocapods.
The following commands have solved it:

Reinstalling:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Updating Packages ("pod install" doesn't install the latest)

```
pod update
```